# jQuery PNG Animate - first frame dont use

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, png, setinterval

I need to make animation took place from the second frame.
Animation running at setInterval() that it is repeated.. so that the first frame I never want to see.

```
(function (a) {
    a.fn.less_loader = function (b) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var b = a(this),
                c = a("<img />").attr("src", "images/loader.png").addClass("loader").css({
                    "background-position": "left bottom"
                });
            b.prepend(c);
            var d = 24;
            c.data("animation", setInterval(function () {
                if (d == 24 * 20) d = 0;
                c.css({
                    "left": " -" + d + "px"
                });
                d = d + 24
            }, 120)); 
        })
    }
})(jQuery)

-----

#wrap .loader {
    width: 480px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

PNG loader is 480x24px

1 frame is 24x24px

It has 20 frames = 480px

**I can show 2-20 frames on animate only!**

**Dot use the first frame**

Thanks